# How can I fix links bootstrap template?

Tags: javascript, html, bootstrap-4

I'm trying to use [startbootstrap-bare](https://github.com/BlackrockDigital/startbootstrap-bare) template. I want to load a different content when a user press `About` (`about.html`) but save a navigation (menu) bar.

But when I change the `href` to

```
<a class="nav-link" href="/about">About</a>
```

and put `about.html` in the same folder with `index.html` it doesn't really work locally at all (like it tries to open `file://about.html` which is obviously a wrong path). And shall I copy the contents of `index.html` to `about.html` or I can only make bootstrap to load its content div instead?

Comment: May be your root directory is different. Can you try `<a class="nav-link" href="./about.html">About</a>`

Comment: @KiranDash it worked! What about _shall I copy the contents of index.html to about.html or I can only make bootstrap to load its content div instead_?

Comment: Depends on what kind of application you want to build. If you are building a multi page application, create a new file like about.html then just copy the content and do adjustments.

Comment: The approach you are suggesting to just load the content div can be achieved through various means: like putting the content in index.html itself and just show/hide based on the click event. But looking at your question, it seems like you are building a multi page application. So let's just keep it simple and build new pages with new content.

Comment: Don't forget to close your question by marking any of the answer below as the correct one. Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May be your root directory is different. Because of which browser is looking for a file in the wrong directory. To fix this you can choose the dot operator like shown below which tells browser to look for the file "about.html" in current directory.

**Solution with dot operator:**

```
<a class="nav-link" href="./about.html">About</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

you should put extension also in href. (Just think you can have an about.html and an about.php existing in the same folder.)
Simply like this, if the files are in the same folder, otherwise you have to add path.

```
<a class="nav-link" href="about.html">About</a>
```